# What is the reason that Satoru Gojo still makes hand signs to activate the Infinity when he made it automatic?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

Gojo is really powerful, and one of the techniques that **greatly** put this statement into play are his Limitless and Infinity Jujutsu techniques. Taken from the *[wiki article on Limitless](https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Limitless):*

> Limitless (無下限, Mukagen?) is an inherited technique passed down within the Gojo Family. This technique brings the concept of "Infinity" into reality, allowing the user to manipulate and distort space at will.

The technique (infinity) was originally manually activated by Gojo, but after his defeat against Toji during his Past Arc, he started training and made the Infinity an automatic technique, by mass, speed, shape, and cursed energy amount:

> [image]

Gojo says the technique is automatic now, but there are instances (present in both anime and manga) where he makes a hand sign to activate the Infinity:

[image]

Leading to this question.. what is the reason that Gojo uses a hand seal when using Infinity when he made it an automatic techniques **years ago, as a teen?**

Comment: I'm guessing It could be the equivalent of anime characters shouting out move names right before attack. The mangaka might be attempting to explicitly show us "the readers" when he actively uses the ability. I can imagine the scene wouldn't be the same if Gojo was just standing and doing nothing while the curses are completely immobilized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like [@Rumpelstiltskin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/42685/rumpelstiltskin) [said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/65952/what-is-the-reason-that-satoru-gojo-still-makes-hand-signs-to-activate-the-infin/65984#comment78232_65952), it's because it's supposed to act as an indicator that he is using his powers, and also to add more flair into the show.

Considering that it's a show which revolves around action and fighting, even if he is dubbed as the 'strongest' he still has to do something to arouse the viewers' interest. It can't possibly be considered a fight if Gojo does practically nothing, as it will make the fight seem too one-sided. As shown in the episode when they met Nobara, Yuji could be seen hugging Gojo out of happiness. It wasn't shown when Gojo actually deactivated Infinity to allow Yuji to do such a thing, which further proves this point. Infinity is something that is somewhat transparent and we can't see it, so we don't actually know when it is activated and when it is not. Gojo doing this hand signal thus helps us to know that he is currently activating Infinity and the attacks being stopped are not due to other causes.

Of course, another theory is that he did this because he is used to constantly doing it as a teenager, but I find the first theory more plausible.

Comment: upd. as stated in ch. 223, sorcerer's prowess is measured in their ability to omit certain rituals while being able to fully activate their technique, but actually using all of those otherwise unnecessary rituals will allow them to output more than 100% effectiveness of that ability